Floor plans of the Stargate Command standing set (SG-1)
Over the run of the Stargate SG-1 series, there have been many shots where characters were continuously followed as they moved between various spaces in Stargate Command.
It appears as though there was a fairly large set incorporating the gate room, control room, briefing room, Hammond's/O'Neill's office, and various connecting corridors and stairs all in one set "complex". There were also other spaces such as the infirmary, commissary, labs (including one with a viewing gallery), guest quarters, etc. which were not necessarily integrated with the gate room complex.
All of this leads me to wonder about the layout of the complete standing set. I understand that in early production, the gate room set was initially assembled in one location and temporarily used there before being moved to its final location for the remainder of the run, so my question relates to the "post-move" location. Are there floor plans?

I could be wrong, I've seen the 'scene' floorplans, of course, that represent the fictional layout, but the following plans, look quite similar...
I know its from SGA, but it was filmed at the same studios (Bridge Studios) as SG-1, so that they still had the set standing and used it when needed (I can't remember the overlap, its been so long):
SG-1 Executive Producer and writer Joseph Mallozzi has a blog, and occasionally posts material from his past projects:
https://josephmallozzi.com/2013/03/20/march-20-2013-2007-silver-wraith-mobile-for-sale-only-used-for-picnicking-and-chasing-down-human-prey-sgc-blueprints/

The other day, someone asked me if I had blueprints of the SGC.  I looked through my old Art Department handouts and these are what I came up with.  From Stargate: Atlantis episode #412, Miller’s Crossing:



As you can see, multiple separate sets, Stage 5, which is large enough to have these multiple sets on, as well as the SGC combined one.
Similarly, SGA has its sets in Stage 6.
https://josephmallozzi.com/2013/02/26/february-26-2013-gearing-up-days-of-stargate-atlantis-past-continues-enemy-at-the-gate/


Once Upon A Time is now using Stage 4 (that once held the Destiny set), Stage 5 (the SGC gate room, control room, conference room, Hammond’s office, the infirmary, and surrounding corridors as well as the Alpha site corridors, control room, and gate room), and Stage 6 (the Atlantis gate room, control room, conference room, infirmary, and surrounding corridors) but there is plenty of stage space still available including the aforementioned monster VFX Stage.

Bridge Studios Set Visit:
http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/originalspirit/destination_vancouver.shtml
(On a side note, I see it was demolished in 2017)

vfx bts:
https://www.thecompanion.app/john-gajdecki-stargate-vfx/
Unfortunately, I have yet to find a plan that showed the layout of the various sets within Stage 5 during SG-1/SGA. Alas, the closest is from the later SGU, with a partial plan of stage 6:

